# Regex for more than 1 First Name before the Middle Initial

Tags: regex

I'm not that good with regular expression and here is my problem:
I want to create a regex that match with a name that has *two or more first name* (e.g. Francis Gabriel).

I came up with the regex `^[A-Z][a-z]{3,30}/s[A-Z][a-z]{3,30}` but 
it only matches with two first name and not all first names.

The regex should match with `John John J. Johnny`.

Comment: what language are you using it in?

Comment: Im currently using java

Comment: How are you defining a first name?  How would handle the name `Francis Scott Key`?  Would "Scott" be a middle name or a second first name?

Comment: I define the first name by matching the middle initial and all the name before the middle initial will be first names, and the input name format should look like this `John John John J. Johnny`

Comment: I don't understand. You could have several first names without a initial in the name right? So catching names before a initial would not be enough?

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: well it is not enough when you have three word first name and after that is the middle initial, and the regex should match name with middle initial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[A-Z][a-z]{3,30}(\\s[A-Z](\\.|[a-z]{2,30})?)*$
```

\s must be used in java when using a Pattern Compiler.
If it is X., we have to validate it, or XYZ
John Johny J.hny -> is wrong
so either . or [a-z] and at least one first name should be there. So, put a * at last of second part to match 0 or more.

**Since java is not supported in this snippet, a JavaScript implementation of same regex is done for you to understand.**

Check it here

```js
var reg=/^[A-Z][a-z]{3,30}(\s[A-Z](\.|[a-z]{2,30})?)*$/;
console.log(reg.test("John john")); // false because second part start with small case
console.log(reg.test("John John"));
console.log(reg.test("John John J."));
console.log(reg.test("John John J. Johny"));
```

Comment: ah so using the `or` in regex in finding the middle initial and if not continue, how foolish of me. Thanks

Comment: Regex is very easy bro. If you look into examples, you will understand nothing. So, learn basics. It will help you out. All d best

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(\S*\s+)(\S*)?\s+\S*?
```

Francis Gabriel - matches:

```
0: [0,10] Francis 
1: [0,9] Francis 
2: [9,9]
```

John John2 J. Johnny - matches:

```
0: [0,11] John John2 
1: [0,5] John 
2: [5,10] John2
```

Comment: sir the regex will only match with two first name, and with just looking for white space is not enough for matching one or more first name.

Comment: I updated my answer.  I wasn't clear what you were looking for. Perhaps updating your question with more examples and what you hope the result would be would help us.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

```
^\w+\s(\w+\s)+\w\.\s\w+$

^\w+\s    match a name a space
(\w+\s)+  followed by at least one more name and space
\w+\.\s   followed by a single letter initial with dot then space
\w+$      followed by a last name
```

## Regex101

Test code:

```
String testInput = "John John P. Johnny";
if (testInput.matches("^\\w+\\s(\\w+\\s)+\\w+\\.\\s\\w+$")) {
    System.out.println("We have a match");
}
```